# Accessing a value in an object of unknown name that is stored in an array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Its hard to give this question a good name. I'll jump right into the example:

```
var people = [
        {
            john: {
                score: 1
            }
        },
            {
            adam: {
                score: 2
            }
        }
    ];
```

I need to loop through this array of objects and get the `score` values, the trick is I don't know the names (`john`, `adam`, ...) but I know each contains a `score` value.

How do I get them? My current code looks like this:

```
var pplArr = [];

for (i=0; i<people.length; i++) {
    for (var key in people[i]) {
        pplArr.push(key);
    }
}

for (j=0; j<pplArr.length; j++) {
    console.log(pplArr[j]);
    //var nameVar = eval(pplArr[j]);
    //console.log(people.[j].nameVar.score)
}
```

The commented section doesn't work since `eval()` returns undefined otherwise I think it would work. I also tried `for (var key in people)` and its variations with limited success. Also my two loops look like they are over-complicated, is there no simpler way?

I'm using AngularJS (ionic) thus I would prefer not to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**.**[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** will help to iterate over array and **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** helps to gets object keys as an array, get first one from array and get the value.

```js
var people = [{
  john: {
    score: 1
  }
}, {
  adam: {
    score: 2
  }
}];

var res = people.map(function(v) {
  return v[Object.keys(v)[0]].score;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I got just one question, is the `i` a leftover or does it serve some purpose? If I remove it I get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know if you have more than one person in each object you can recourse in the object looking for all properties named score and return the values in an array like this:

```
function getAllProperties(o, p){
    var properties = [];

    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (typeof o[k] === "object") {
            properties = properties.concat(getAllProperties(o[k], p));
        } else if (k === p) {
            properties.push(o[k]);
        }
    });

    return properties;
}

console.log(getAllProperties(people, "score"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the score of each object in people array, you could do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    var person = people[i];
    for (var key in person) {
            for (score in person[key]) {
                console.log(person[key][score])
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: @max7 Yes my bad. missed out a loop